# How to define a function that determines the argument without a delimiter?

Tags: macros, delimiters

### Question:

Is it possible to define a function, e.g. `\myFunction`, that does not require delimiters, that would consider the first string after its own name to be its argument? e.g. `\myFunctionfoo` (or possibly `\myFunction foo` would be parsed as as `\myFunction{foo}` ?

I'm only familiar with commands defined using the `\newcommand{}[]{}` function, which I believe automatically expects the argument to be wrapped in `{ }`; however, I'm aware of the (controversial :D) functionality of some commands that handle simple cases like `\frac12` that functions equivalently to `\frac{1}{2}` and so am hoping it is possible to define something that behaves similarly.

### Context:

I'm using a platform that integrates KaTeX with other programming languages and we're looking for ways to clean up the code, so that it is more readable. Currently we're getting a *lot* of nested calls to the different languages e.g.

```
$\left\{ \frac{\eval{foo}\eval{bar}}{2}\right\}^{\eval{baz}}$
```

where `\eval{foo/bar/baz}` returns some tex-appropriate string generated by one of the other programming languages.

These expressions are *everywhere* making the number of curly braces increase to a significant degree, and making the code ever-harder to read. N.B. the is just an example, for clarity, actual instances involve far more calls to `\eval{}`; essentially everything that is not a KaTeX command will be wrapped in this way, so it gets ugly, fast.

Now, 95% of our calls using `\eval{ }` actually just call a single variables or function (i.e. something naturally limited in scope), so the braces aren't actually necessary as the argument is unambiguously the next string (whether `\myFunction<string>` or `\myFunction <string>`  (N.B. space before *and* after `<string>`).

N.B. we will maintain a fully-delimited version of the function as well, this is just for unambiguous calls, mostly to variable names.

Comment: If you are *absolutely sure* that there will *always* be a space it could be as simple as `\def\eval#1 {...}`. But this will then miserably fail with something like `\frac{\eval foo \eval baz}{denominator}`.

Comment: @campa I'll have to look into how KaTeX deals with `\def` and see if that works. A quick test didn't give the desired results, but I may have to define it differently for it to be handled properly. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: do you mean you need a definition that works with katex?, if so, fancy tex definitions using delimited macros are unlikely to work and a javascript definition that works for katex would be off topic here. or are you looking for a tex definition for processing the file as tex? (In which case is luatex an option?)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, making it work with KaTeX is an eventual requirement, and I see that they support things like `\def` `\gdef` `\let` etc. however, they don't seem to be working as expected, on our platform, so I have reached out to the chief programmer to determine if the issue is our current implementation or a general limitation. I definitely want to avoid a js solution, if possible (not sure what etiquette is if that turns out to be the case: do I just close my own question as off-topic?). I will update as soon as I hear back.

Comment: we see more mathjax than katex questions but issues same, so long as people can test answers using tex it's on topic but if you need javascropt specifics then no. I'd be rather surprised if katex supports the kind of  delimited argument and `\expandafter` low level tex tricks you would need to recognise an argument (compared to just looking ahead with a regex in js code) certainly mathjax wouldn't even though it supports simple `\def` and `\newcommand` uses.

Comment: According to the [KaTeX site](https://katex.org/docs/supported.html#macros), `\expandafter` is indeed supported, as well as a handful of others: `\char`, `\mathchoice`, `\TextOrMath`, `\@ifstar`, `\@ifnextchar`,  `\@firstoftwo `, `\@secondoftwo`,  `\relax`, and  `\noexpand` (I have no experience working with these though, just trying to provide additional context).

Comment: How about define `\evalfoo` as `eval{foo}`, and `\evalbar` as `\eval{bar}`, etc.  Then 95% of your `\eval` style invocations can be simplified?  This assumes you there are a standard, known set of arguments to `\eval` than comprise 95% of the invocations.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes very clever, and - although there are not standard, known, arguments, I think it would be possible to have these defined programmatically, not sure it'll work for my particular case, because of other elements, but this does address the question; I'll certainly give it a shot! Thanks for taking the time to share!

Comment: While TeX will break if such macros are encountered wholly unexpectedly, it would be trivial to define an `\evaldeclare` macro such that `\evaldeclare{foo}`, invoked once in the preamble, would define `\evalfoo` for use ever after.  For example,  `\newcommand\evaldeclare[1]{\expandafter\def\csname eval#1\endcsname{\eval{#1}}}`

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you can add also space, it is easy:

`\def\myFunction#1 {[something to do]#1}`.

TeX expects that the argument should end with space (in this case). Certainly, the usage is `\myFunction foo bar` and the argument is `foo`.

Comment: Thank you for this! I'm still waiting on our programmer to be able to test it, but this looks promising. I will update as soon as I'm able to test! Thank you for your time and help!